# How to mock Storage file download in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a controller method that allows the user to download a file from the S3 using the storage fascade:

```
public function download(Export $export): StreamedResponse
{
    return Storage::disk('s3-data-exports')->download($export->path);
}
```

I am trying to create a test for this but am running into trouble with what the disk method should return:

```
public function testClientCanDownloadExport()
{
    Storage::fake('s3-data-exports');

    $export = factory(Export::class)->create();

    $file = new File(base_path('tests/_data/ricardo/IntakeDataExport.csv'));
    
    Storage::shouldReceive('disk')
        ->with('s3-data-exports')
        ->andReturn() // <--- what goes in here?
        ->shouldReceive('download')
        ->andReturn($file);

    $this->json('GET', route('exports.download', $export->id))
        ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

What is it that the disk method should return in order for the chaining to work and the next shouldReceive to run correctly?

Comment: the method `disk($name = null)` returns an instance of a class implementing the interface `\Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```php
public function testClientCanDownloadExport()
{
    $storage = Storage::fake('s3-data-exports');

    // Create fake file
    $file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('IntakeDataExport.csv', 100);

    // Store fake file on the s3-data-exports disk
    $filePath = $file->store('csv', 's3-data-exports');

    // Create export and set the path attribute to match the saved file's path
    $export = factory(Export::class)->create(['path' => $filePath]);

    Storage::shouldReceive('disk')
        ->with('s3-data-exports')
        ->andReturn($storage)
        ->shouldReceive('download')
        ->andReturn($file);

    $this->get(route('exports.download', $export->id))
        ->assertStatus(200);
}
```